# Font shape undefined when using autoinst

Tags: fonts, autoinst

I want to create my fonts using `autoinst` script for use with `pdflatex`.

For this I run the commands `autoinst example-regular.otf` `autoinst example-italic.otf` `autoinst example-bold.otf` and `autoinst example-bolditalic.otf`.

Now I'm running `texhash`and `updmap --enable Map example.map` and all works.
But when I try to use the font in all installed shapes like in the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{example}
%\pdfmapfile{=example.map}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
test\enspace\textit{test}\enspace\textbf{test}\enspace\textit{\textbf{test}}
\end{document}
```

I'll only get the regular font shape and for the other shapes warnings like `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/example-TLF/m/it' undefined (Font) using 'T1/example-TLF/m/n' instead on input line 10.` and this for all shapes so the result looks like the following:

[image: test]

Comment: Try running `autoinst` once, specifying all of the font files you want included in a single family of fonts. `autoinst example-regular.otf example-italic.otf example-bold.otf example-bold-italic.otf` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr Care to make that an answer?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Done. Though it hardly seemed substantive enough for an answer ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a single family with several shapes/weights, you need to run `autoinst` once on all the relevant fonts, rather than running it on each font separately. If the fonts are `<example-regular>.otf`, `<example-italic>.otf`, `<example-bold>.otf` and `<example-bold-italic>.otf`, for instance, run

```
autoinst <example-regular>.otf <example-italic>.otf <example-bold>.otf <example-bold-italic>.otf
```

Otherwise, I think you'll end up with a different font family for each shape which will not support standard shape-switching and weight-switching commands such as `\textit{}` and `\bfseries`.